# Process waiting for input from other process

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, inotify

I need to have a mechanism wherein 2 process should communicate. 
Process A will do some job and wait for input [file path] from another process B. Each time Linux machine is rebooted this should happen.

The number of times this happens is controlled by the count in process A.

Thought of doing this using systemd service, and could not get any input.

Answer (score 1):

A way to go about this would be by using a socket. Of course, this implies that you need to use network socket libraries in your processes, but this is the most common way of allowing two processes to communicate.

Since the two processes are on the same machine, I suggest you configure a systemd unix socket.

Then, Process A can connect to the socket to listen, and process B can send data through it.

As long as your processes are fully automatic, listening and sending data by themselves and require no manual intervention, it does not matter whether they are systemd services or not - just make them log information in files or to journald, so you can debug what's happening.

Here are some links that would help you start with this:
**[systemd.socket manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html)**
**[A short guide about setting up a service with a socket in systemd](https://www.linux.com/blog/end-road-systemds-socket-units)**
**[The general idea behind inter-process communication in C](http://www.it.uom.gr/teaching/distrubutedSite/dsIdaLiu/labs/lab2_1/sockets.html)**

Comment: Thank you for the help.